# CSS drop down menu disappear behind content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I searched for similar topics but none of the solutions work for me. My CSS drop down menu disappears behind another content area.

```
#poshmenu {
padding-top: 10px;
 }

#cssmenu ul {
   margin: 0;

   padding: 4px 6px 0;

   line-height: 100%;
   border-radius: 1em;
   font: normal 0.5333333333333333em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   width: auto;
    }

    #cssmenu li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 4px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;

    }
    #cssmenu a,
    #cssmenu a:link {
     font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 13px;
   color: #4B4B4B;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 5px 20px;
   margin: 0;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;


    }
   #cssmenu a:hover {
   background: #000;

    }
   #cssmenu .active a,
   #cssmenu li:hover > a {

background: #5a565a url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
background: #666666 url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
color: #666;
border-top: solid 1px  #f8f8f8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
    #cssmenu li:hover li a {

    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
     }
     #cssmenu ul ul a:hover {

    background: #403d40 url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     }
    #cssmenu li:hover > ul {
     display: block;

       }
     #cssmenu ul ul {
       display: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 185px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 0;
     background: url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 0;
     border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

      }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
         padding: 3px;

           }
         #cssmenu ul ul a,
         #cssmenu ul ul a:link {
         font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 12px;

                 }
          #cssmenu ul:after {
content: '.';
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;  
     }
   * html #cssmenu ul {
       height: 1%;

      }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
         <div class="poshmenu">

         <div id='cssmenu'>
           <ul>
             <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Wood</span></a>
      <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Oak</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Sycamore</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Ash</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a> </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="imagecontainerindex"><img src="images/indeximagetext.jpg" width="800"               height="320" /></div>
```

The 'Wood' menu pops behind the image below. I have hunted for the overflow: hidden; but there isn't one and I've tried z-indexes to no avail.

Comment: Please post your code to jsfiddle.net or a similar live preview website and share the link with us so we can try to help you with your problem.

Comment: Not reproducable: http://jsbin.com/eletOgI/1/edit Perhaps you just need a higher z-index?

Comment: In your `#cssmenu ul ul {` rule, have you tried reducing the `top` from 40 to say 26px?

Comment: I would have said changing the Z index, my website was dropping the menu down behind the images so had to change them and it fixed it

Comment: I've ramped the z-index right up and that seems to have worked. Thanks so much; so simple!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the main menu bar allowing drop-down items to disappear behind the main content or other elements.

My solution was not in the CSS3 or z-index but in HTML and the positioning of elements.

The pages that didn't work were laid out like this...

I had the same problem but changing the z-index value made no difference because the problem lies not with the CSS3 but with the hthl.

I solved by changing the order of element on the html page. It took four days on and off trying to solve this one.

```
[code]
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div id="mainbody">
            <article></article>
            ...etc...
        </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
[code]
```

I solved it by simply moving the navigation section out of the header, like so...

```
[code]
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <nav>
        </nav>
        <div id="mainbody">
            <article></article>
            ...etc...
        </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
[code]
```

Having the nav block inside the header meant that it was constrained by whatever size the header bar was set to.